# React Native - Open screen when unauthenticated

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble implementing authentication with react native and firebase auth.
This is my first react native app and I have limited knowledge

The Behavior I want is the same as BlaBlaCar's:

A bottom tab menu with 5 menu itens, 4 of them need authentication. If user is not authenticated, a screen or modal opens with login/register forms
If user is authenticated, he can actually use screens

So, my code is working so far but I don't know if is the best approach

I thought about 2 ways of implementing this:

1. I create a user context and check in every screen if user is there (this is what I did and it works)
2. I create 2 routes, one sending routes to login and another to real components

The problem with the way I'm doing is that I need to check for user context in every screen and this seems wrong

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

My opinionated approach for solving this challenge is :

When the user signed in, save the authentication token in global storage ( either Context API or Redux, or Async Storage).

When the user visits the protected screen, check if the user is authenticated or not. Show  protected content or Login model